# Crystal Report 2008 - How to generate latest 12 months figures report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a query report from two different tables in the database, the records in the two tables are as below:

1) Sales Table

```
InvoiceNo   InvoiceDate   SaleAmount   Customer   OtherFields…..
 00099      02/09/2014     3500          B
 00101      08/21/2014     8700          A
 00108      11/25/2014     3200          C  
 01001      05/01/2015     1500          A
 01002      05/25/2015     1800          C
 01015      07/08/2015     1700          A
 01020      07/18/2015     2000          A
 01028      07/29/2015     3000          B
 01041      08/02/2015     5000          A
 01042      08/03/2015     4300          A
 01050      09/09/2015     1900          C
 01200      09/28/2015     2000          A
```

2) Payment Table

```
InvoiceNo   PayDate     PayAmount  Customer   OtherFields…..
 00101      11/25/2014   5000        C  
 00150      12/10/2014   8000        B
 00180      01/01/2015   3500        A
 00300      02/20/2015   4000        A
 00333      03/02/2015   6000        A
 00488      03/10/2015   3000        A
 00500      03/19/2015   4000        B
 00890      05/22/2015   7000        A
 01041      09/17/2015   2800        A
```

**Question**: How to generate a crystal report that can produce the result as
          below, eg: Customer A:

```
Customer: A
Month       TotalSalesAmount        TotalPayAmount
Nov-2014           0                        0
Dec-2014           0                        0   
Jan-2015           0                      3500
Feb-2015           0                      4000
Mar-2015           0                      9000
Apr-2015           0                         0  
May-2015        1500                      7000  
Jun-2015           0                         0
Jul-2015        3700                         0
Aug-2015        9300                         0
Sep-2015        2000                      2800
Oct-2015           0                         0

MonthAverages   :   Latest3Months       Latest6Months       Latest12Months
AveragesSales:        3766.67             2750.00               1375.00
AveragesPay:           933.33             1633.33               2191.67
```

**Question1**: If I enter Customer A, the above result generated, if enter 
           Customer B, B result will be generated and so for other customer?

**Question2:** How to always generate a latest 12 months report like above?

**Question3:** How to show a month=0 amount while there are no records on that 
           month, eg: June, July, August and October of Year2015 for Payment 
           Table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How close are you to creating your report? If you haven't done anything yet and don't know how to start I suggest you google some tutorials and at least try first.

Comment: Q3: I tried to group the date by month, it worked only month with records (i.e. sum up the amount), but months without records, it will not show 0 amount.

Comment: Q2: I can use the select expert to choose the date range,but  just wanted to know any other way to do it or not.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and add a representation of your current generated report?